# Upgrading PostgreSQL to 15.3 with old data

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-10, dbmigrate

I'm running Postgres 10.4 in the docker container for [Posit Connect (https://posit.co/products/enterprise/connect/) application. The latest version of Posit Connect requires Postgres 15.3.

When I updated the Postgres container image to 15.3, I got the below error. After reading I know why this error pops up.

`2023-06-19 11:16:21.027 UTC [1] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with the server 2023-06-19 11:16:21.027 UTC [1] DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 15.3 (Debian 15.3-1.pgdg120+1).`

Since the PSQL is running inside a container I'm struggling to migrate the data to the new PG version with the available documentation.

Tried the `pgdumpall` method but since the DB is in the container unable to execute the final command `pg_dumpall -p 5432 | psql -d postgres -p 5433`. it is throwing errors.

I'm looking for a solution to migrate all the data from the old (PG 10.4) Postgres format to the new version.

Comment: I don't have the time to come up with a complete answer right now but I suggest you research how to create a virtual network of two containers. Then you can modify the `psql` command to connect to the new container using the `-h` option.